# C++. What's the best way to initialize multiple static variables in a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, static, static-variables

There are class with multiple static variables, e.g.

```
    template<class T>
    struct A
    {
    // some code...
        static int i;
        static short s;
        static float f;
        static double d;
    // other static variables
    };
```

The main way is to use the full template name

```
template<typename T> 
int A<T>::i = 0;
template<typename T> 
short A<T>::s = 0;
template<typename T> 
float A<T>::f = 0.;
template<typename T> 
double A<T>::d = 0.;
// other inits of static variables
```

this solution contains a lot of the same code  (`template<typename T>` and `A<T>`)
And if the template has several types, this leads to increase this code, e.g.

```
struct B<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{
   // some code
   static int i;
   //other static variables
};
...
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
int B<T1, T2, T3, T4>::i = 0;
//other static variable
```

It looks ok for 1-2 static variables, but if you need more it looks terrible
I think about using macros, something like this

```
#define AStaticInit(TYPE) template<typename T> TYPE A<T>
AStaticInit(int)::i = 0;
AStaticInit(short)::s = 0;
AStaticInit(float)::f = 0.;
AStaticInit(double)::d  = 0.;
// other inits of static variables
#undef TArray
```

But perhaps there are better options for initializing several static variables in a template class with minimum code?

Comment: Why do you have so many static members in the first place?

Comment: @Artyer
I found the same example in someone else's code, and so far I have not figured out the need for so many variables, but it was hard to look at it, because the names of variables, classes and types did not consist of a couple of characters =)
but it became interesting how it can be refactored into a more readable form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them `inline` to be able to give them initializers:

```cpp
    template<class T>
    struct A
    {
    // some code...
        inline static int i = 0;
        inline static short s = 0;
        inline static float f = 0.f;
        inline static double d = 0.;
    // other static variables
    };
```

Comment: But one note. It's available from c++17

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class that doesn't need a template and put all your static variables in it.

```
    struct Base
    {
    // some code...
        static int i;
        static short s;
        static float f;
        static double d;
    // other static variables
    };

    template<class T>
    struct A : public Base
    {
    // some code...
    };
```

Comment: This has different behaviour because there is no longer one static variable for each type `A<T>` (`&A<void>::i == &A<void*>::i` when that wasn't the case before)

Comment: @Artyer yes that's true.  But if you need a different set of variables for each template type, then you need boilerplate for declaring and initializing those variables - there's no avoiding it.